# Set a directory by default on BASH windows

Tags: windows, bash, unix

The problem I am having is that every time I open bash, it takes me to an unwanted directory, so I have to type the commands cd /mnt/c to get to my PC files like downloads, documents etc. How do I set a directory by default when I open bash?

Comment: Create a `.profile` or `.bashrc` and have a cd command as the last part of it. This might break any type of `Open bash here` shortcuts though.

Answer (score 11):

The `bash.exe` Windows executable that starts Bash on Windows implicitly makes the *current* directory its startup directory.

That means that you can simply **modify the shortcut file that opens Bash and change its `Start in:` field to open Bash in the directory of choice** (specify a regular Windows path; it is automatically translated into a `/mnt/c`-prefixed path when Bash starts).

- *Caveat*: The official `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` shortcut file (in the Start Menu) passes `~` as the startup directory as part of the `Target:` field; simply remove  `~` from the `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~` value in `Target:`, and then fill in the `Start in:` field.

Of course, you can create new shortcut files, each with its own startup directory, if desired.

---

#### Adding a `Bash Console Here` command to the context menu of folders in File Explorer

<sup>**Update**: **[Prerelease build 17666](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/releases/tag/17666) now comes with a context menu built in** - however, it **requires you to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> before right-clicking** in order to access it; the solution below may therefore still be of interest if you want the command to show *unconditionally*.</sup>

If you **save the following text in a `*.reg` file and open (double-click) it**, you'll be prompted to import the definitions into your user-specific registry hive.

After import, you'll find a `Bash Console Here` command in the context menu of folders in File Explorer, and also when you click in the empty space inside a folder.
On selecting that command, a Bash console window will open in that folder.

*Caveat*: Because an aux. `cmd.exe` call must be used to change the directory before invoking `bash.exe`, the console window will have `cmd.exe`'s icon and will be grouped with regular `cmd.exe` in the taskbar.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,4c,00,4f,00,43,00,41,00,4c,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,\
  00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,6c,00,78,00,73,00,73,00,5c,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,\
  68,00,2e,00,69,00,63,00,6f,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="cmd /c cd \"%V\" && bash.exe"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,4c,00,4f,00,43,00,41,00,4c,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,\
  00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,6c,00,78,00,73,00,73,00,5c,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,\
  68,00,2e,00,69,00,63,00,6f,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="cmd /c cd \"%1\" && bash.exe"
```

Alternatively, you can use the following **PowerShell snippet** to create the registry entries:

```powershell
$null = 0..1 | % {
  $key = New-Item -Force ('HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory{0}\shell\BashConsoleHere' -f ('', '\Background')[$_])
  $key | New-ItemProperty -Name '(Default)' -Value 'Bash Console Here' -Type String
  $key | New-ItemProperty -Name 'Icon' -Value '%LOCALAPPDATA%\lxss\bash.ico' -Type ExpandString
  $key = New-Item -Force "$($key.PsPath)\command"
  $key | New-ItemProperty -Name '(Default)' -Value "cmd /c cd `"$(('%1', '%V')[$_])`" && bash.exe" -Type String
}
```

To remove the entries later:

```
0..1 | % {
  Remove-Item -Recurse -LiteralPath ('HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory{0}\shell\BashConsoleHere' -f ('', '\Background')[$_])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have to create it, but add this line to your `.bashrc` in your `$HOME` directory (usually `/home/user/`):

`cd /mnt/c`

Keep in mind that just like Jim had said, "This might break any type of `Open bash here` shortcuts though".

You can read a little bit more about this in this thread here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140602/how-do-i-start-all-shell-sessions-in-a-directory-other-than-home

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility -- and I have to emphasize that you *really* have to understand what you're doing, is to set your `$HOME` directory to `/mnt/c`.

You can only do this if

- `/mnt/c` is *always* mounted.
- Your bash user has total read/write/execute permissions to `/mnt/c`
- `/mnt/c` is *not* accessible to anyone you don't want having access to it -- your `$HOME` directory will contain `.ssh/` which *must* be private.
- You can copy/move all of the files from your original `$HOME` directory to `/mnt/c`.

You can do this using

```
usermod --home /mnt/c
```

or by changing your home directory in `/etc/passwd`

Caveat: doing this wrong can leave you unable to log in, or leave your account vulnerable.